# How to hide paypal login option on payment screen

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have setup the express checkout process integration in asp.net mvc. When user is redirected to paypal website after submission, there is option to login using paypal or sign up new account and below that there is option to pay using credit card or debit? can i disable the login screen ? i would like to show only credit or debit card option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable the PayPal option, but you could add some parameters to force the credit card option to be more prominent.  Just add the following parameters to your SetExpressCheckout request...

- SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
- LANDINGPAGE=Billing
- USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

Comment: I am using the following sample application and i am not sure where i can set the above mentioned attributes?https://bitbucket.org/jhelmink/paypalexpresscheckoutmvc/src

Comment: It would go in [SetExpressCheckout](https://bitbucket.org/jhelmink/paypalexpresscheckoutmvc/src/3db03cd05fa148ffaa122acbb0b1a03bc94aa867/PayPalMvc/Requests/SetExpressCheckoutRequest.cs?at=default).

Comment: I have added the above fields but page appears same as it was before.

Comment: i have set LANDINGPAGE=Billing, but it does not work. it should however open up the credit card option instead of login screen. what could be the issue?

Comment: It shows now to login as paypal or use guest login? when i click on guest login it then open up a page.. this two page process is quite annoying? how can i make to open up payment page directly ?

Comment: PayPal is split testing different versions of the checkout pages for Express Checkout.  sometimes you'll get the old one, which shows the full credit card form by default, and other times you'll get the new one, which just has a little button to pay with credit card.  Unfortunately, we can't control which one you'll see, but using those parameters will make sure the guest checkout option is always available.

Comment: how do i know the version which i am passing "SetExpressCheckoutRequestType" i mean where can i find the version i cant see my documentation along with sdk?